# My database isn't updating my rows using SQLite - everything looks perfect to me

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update

There is a bunch of moving parts here so I will try to be thorough:
My first Activity is a form that creates a Customer object by gathering most of the Customer object's fields and passing in 'null' for the credit card info fields. Here is the model "Customer" class and the Activity that gathers the info. So far, so good.

```
public class Customer {

    private UUID customerId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String streetAddress;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;
    private String email;
    private String cardNum;
    private String cardExp;
    private String cvv;
    private boolean isVisa;

    private List<Session> mSessionList;

    // Going to have to add billing info somehow. Maybe an inner class


    public Customer() {

        customerId = UUID.randomUUID();
        firstName = "firstName";
        lastName = "lastName";
        streetAddress = "streetAddress";
        city = "city";
        state = "state";
        zipCode = "zip";
        email = "email";
        cardNum = "cardNum";
        cardExp = "cardExp";
        cvv = "cvv";
        isVisa = true;

    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String streetAddress, String city, String state,
                    String zipCode, String email, String cardNum, String cardExp, String cvv, boolean isVisa) {
        this.customerId = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.email = email;
        this.cardNum = cardNum;
        this.cardExp = cardExp;
        this.cvv = cvv;
        this.isVisa = true;
    }

    public String getCardNum() {
        return cardNum;
    }

    public boolean isVisa() {
        return isVisa;
    }

    public void setIsVis(boolean ans){
        isVisa = ans;
    }

    public void setCardNum(String cardNum) {
        this.cardNum = cardNum;
    }

    public String getCardExp() {
        return cardExp;
    }

    public void setCardExp(String cardExp) {
        this.cardExp = cardExp;
    }

    public String getCvv() {
        return cvv;
    }

    public void setCvv(String cvv) {
        this.cvv = cvv;
    }

    public UUID getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getStreetAddress() {
        return streetAddress;
    }

    public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Session> getSessionList() {
        return mSessionList;
    }

    public void addSession(Session session){
        mSessionList.add(session);
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class NewCustomerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CustomerList mCustomerList = CustomerList.get(this);

    Button mCancelButton, mAddButton;
    android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton mCameraButton;
    EditText mFirstName, mLastName, mAddress, mCity, mZip, mEmail;
    ImageView mCustomerPic;
    Spinner mState;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_new_customer);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.logged_in_fragment_container_2);

        if (fragment == null){
            fragment = new LoggedInFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.logged_in_fragment_container_2, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        mCancelButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        mAddButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.billing_info_button);
        mCameraButton = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
        mCustomerPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.new_customer_pic);
        mFirstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tv_first_name);
        mLastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tv_last_name);
        mAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        mCity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
        mState = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_state);
        mZip = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tv_zip);
        mEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.tv_email);

        mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city, zipcode, email, state;

                if(mFirstName.getText().toString().equals("") || mLastName.getText().toString().equals("") ||
                        mAddress.getText().toString().equals("") || mCity.getText().toString().equals("") ||
                        mZip.getText().toString().equals("") || mEmail.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(NewCustomerActivity.this, "You must fill out all form fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    firstName = mFirstName.getText().toString();
                    lastName = mLastName.getText().toString();
                    streetAddress = mAddress.getText().toString();
                    city = mCity.getText().toString();
                    zipcode = mZip.getText().toString();
                    email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                    state = mState.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    Customer customer = new Customer(firstName, lastName, streetAddress,
                            city, state, zipcode, email, null, null, null, true);

                    mCustomerList.addCustomer(customer);

                    UUID customerID = customer.getCustomerId();


                    Intent intent = new Intent(NewCustomerActivity.this, CustomerInfoActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(CustomerInfoActivity.CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID, customerID);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

    }



    public void goToCustomerListActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomerListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

Now, when the user presses the mAddButton I pass the UUID of the Customer object to the new Activity via an intent and write the Customer object with the null values for the credit card fields to the database and so far everything works. On the next screen I get the intent, find that Customer in the database and populate the non-editable fields. Below these fields are the editable fields to fill in the credit card info. I enter the credit card info and add these fields to the Customer object and it seems to work great ("I've used log statements to test it"). But when I check my database the credit card fields are still null. Is there something wrong with my database methods? Here is all of my code dealing with the database. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I'm trying hard to learn this stuff.

```
public class CustomerDbSchema {

    public static final class CustomerTable{
        public static final String NAME = "customers";

        public static final class Cols {
            public static final String CUSTOMER_ID = "customer_id";
            public static final String FIRST_NAME = "fist_name";
            public static final String LAST_NAME = "last_name";
            public static final String STREET_ADDRESS = "street_address";
            public static final String CITY = "city";
            public static final String STATE = "state";
            public static final String ZIPCODE = "zip_code";
            public static final String EMAIL = "email";
            public static final String CARD_NUM = "card_num";
            public static final String CARD_EXP = "card_exp";
            public static final String CVV = "cvv";
            public static final String IS_VISA = "is_visa";
        }
    }

    public static final class SessionTable{
        public static final String NAME = "sessions";

        public static final class Cols {
            public static final String SESSION_ID = "session_id";
            public static final String IS_COMPLETED = "is_completed";
            public static final String DATE = "date";
            public static final String CUSTOMER_ID = "customer_id";
        }
    }
}
```

My helper class:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "customer.db";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + CustomerTable.NAME + "(" +
        " _id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        CustomerTable.Cols.CUSTOMER_ID + ", " +
        CustomerTable.Cols.FIRST_NAME + ", " +
        CustomerTable.Cols.LAST_NAME + ", " +
        CustomerTable.Cols.STREET_ADDRESS + ", " +
        CustomerTable.Cols.CITY + ", " +
        CustomerTable.Cols.STATE + ", " +
        CustomerTable.Cols.ZIPCODE + ", " +
        CustomerTable.Cols.EMAIL + ", " +
        CustomerTable.Cols.CARD_NUM + ", " +
        CustomerTable.Cols.CARD_EXP + ", " +
        CustomerTable.Cols.CVV + ", " +
        CustomerTable.Cols.IS_VISA +")");
        db.execSQL("create table " + SessionTable.NAME + "(" +
        " _id integer primary key autoincrement, "  +
        SessionTable.Cols.SESSION_ID + ", " +
        SessionTable.Cols.DATE + ", " +
        SessionTable.Cols.IS_COMPLETED + ", " +
        SessionTable.Cols.CUSTOMER_ID + ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Cursor wrapper class:

```
public class CustomerCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {

    public CustomerCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    public Customer getCustomer(){
        String customerID = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.CUSTOMER_ID));
        String firstName = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.FIRST_NAME));
        String lastName = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.LAST_NAME));
        String streetAddress = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.STREET_ADDRESS));
        String city = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.CITY));
        String state = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.STATE));
        String zip = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.ZIPCODE));
        String email = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.EMAIL));
        String cardNum = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.CARD_NUM));
        String cardExp = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.CARD_EXP));
        String cvv = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.CVV));
        int isVisa = getInt(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.IS_VISA));

        Customer customer = new Customer(firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city,
                state, zip, email, cardNum, cardExp, cvv, isVisa != 0);
        return customer;
    }
}
```

Finally the Singleton class that holds much of the logic for editing and updating the databases. Please check out the method updateCustomer

```
public class CustomerList {
    private static CustomerList sCustomerList;

    private List<Customer> mCustomers;
    private List<Session> mSessions;
    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    public static CustomerList get(Context context) {

        if(sCustomerList == null){
            sCustomerList = new CustomerList(context);
        }
        return sCustomerList;
    }

    private CustomerList(Context context) {

            mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
            mDatabase = new DbHelper(mContext).getWritableDatabase();

    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomers(){
        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

        CustomerCursorWrapper cursor = queryCustomers(null, null);
        try {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                customers.add(cursor.getCustomer());
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return customers;
    }

    public List<Session> getSessions() {
        List<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<>();

        SessionCursorWrapper cursor = querySessions(null, null);
        try {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                sessions.add(cursor.getSession());
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return sessions;
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer c){
        ContentValues values = getCustomerContentValues(c);
        mDatabase.insert(CustomerTable.NAME, null, values);
    }

    public void addSession(Session s){
        ContentValues values = getSessionContentValues(s);
        mDatabase.insert(SessionTable.NAME, null, values);
    }

    public Customer getCustomer(UUID id) {
        CustomerCursorWrapper cursor = queryCustomers(
                CustomerTable.Cols.CUSTOMER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { id.toString() }
        );
        try{
            if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
                return null;
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getCustomer();
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    public void updateCustomer(Customer c){
        String uuidString = c.getCustomerId().toString();
        ContentValues values = getCustomerContentValues(c);

        mDatabase.update(CustomerTable.NAME, values, CustomerTable.Cols.CUSTOMER_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{uuidString});
    }

    public Session getSession(UUID id) {
        SessionCursorWrapper cursor = querySessions(
                SessionTable.Cols.SESSION_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{id.toString()}
        );
        try {
            if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
                return null;
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getSession();
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    public void updateSession(Session s){
        String uuidString = s.getSessionId().toString();
        ContentValues values = getSessionContentValues(s);

        mDatabase.update(SessionTable.NAME, values, SessionTable.Cols.SESSION_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {uuidString});
    }

    private static ContentValues getCustomerContentValues(Customer customer){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CustomerTable.Cols.CUSTOMER_ID, customer.getCustomerId().toString());
        values.put(CustomerTable.Cols.FIRST_NAME, customer.getFirstName());
        values.put(CustomerTable.Cols.LAST_NAME, customer.getLastName());
        values.put(CustomerTable.Cols.STREET_ADDRESS, customer.getStreetAddress());
        values.put(CustomerTable.Cols.CITY, customer.getCity());
        values.put(CustomerTable.Cols.STATE, customer.getState());
        values.put(CustomerTable.Cols.ZIPCODE, customer.getZipCode());
        values.put(CustomerTable.Cols.EMAIL, customer.getEmail());
        values.put(CustomerTable.Cols.CARD_NUM, customer.getCardNum());
        values.put(CustomerTable.Cols.CARD_EXP, customer.getCardExp());
        values.put(CustomerTable.Cols.CVV, customer.getCvv());
        values.put(CustomerTable.Cols.IS_VISA, customer.isVisa() ? 1 : 0);
        return values;

    }

    private static ContentValues getSessionContentValues(Session session){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SessionTable.Cols.SESSION_ID, session.getSessionId().toString());
        values.put(SessionTable.Cols.DATE, session.getDate().getTime());
        values.put(SessionTable.Cols.IS_COMPLETED, session.isCompleted() ? 1 : 0);
        values.put(SessionTable.Cols.CUSTOMER_ID, session.getCusomerID().toString());
        return values;
    }

    private CustomerCursorWrapper queryCustomers(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs){
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
                CustomerTable.NAME,
                null,// columns - null selects all columns
                whereClause,
                whereArgs,
                null, // groupBy
                null, // having
                null //orderBy
                );
        return new CustomerCursorWrapper(cursor);
    }

    private SessionCursorWrapper querySessions(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs){
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
                SessionTable.NAME,
                null,// columns - null selects all columns
                whereClause,
                whereArgs,
                null, // groupBy
                null, // having
                null //orderBy
        );
        return new SessionCursorWrapper(cursor);
    }
}
```

Here is the class where I call the update method:

```
public class CustomerInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID = "current_customer_id";
    CustomerList mCustomerList = CustomerList.get(this);
    RadioGroup mCreditType;
    EditText mCardNum;
    EditText mCardExp;
    EditText mCVV;
    Customer customer;
    Button mSessionsButton;
    Button mHomeButton;
    Button mEditButton;
    Button mUpdateOrEditButton;
    UUID customerID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_info);



        EditText mFullName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.full_name_et);
        EditText mAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address_et);
        EditText mCity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.city_et);
        EditText mState = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.state_et);
        EditText mZip = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zipCod_et);
        EditText mEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_et);
        mCreditType = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        mCardNum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.card_num_tv);
        mCardExp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.expiration_tv);
        mCVV = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cvv_tv);

        mFullName.setEnabled(false);
        mAddress.setEnabled(false);
        mCity.setEnabled(false);
        mState.setEnabled(false);
        mZip.setEnabled(false);
        mEmail.setEnabled(false);


        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.logged_in_fragment_container_3);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new LoggedInFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.logged_in_fragment_container_3, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        customerID = (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID);
        customer = mCustomerList.getCustomer(customerID);

        mFullName.setText(customer.getFirstName() + " " + customer.getLastName());
        mFullName.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        mAddress.setText(customer.getStreetAddress());
        mAddress.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        mCity.setText(customer.getCity());
        mCity.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        mState.setText(customer.getState());
        mState.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        mZip.setText(customer.getZipCode());
        mZip.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        mEmail.setText(customer.getEmail());
        mEmail.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));


        mSessionsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.view_sessions_button);
        mHomeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go_home_button);
        mEditButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.edit_info_button);

        mUpdateOrEditButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update_create_button);
        mUpdateOrEditButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mCardNum.getText().toString().equals("") || mCardExp.getText().toString().equals("") ||
                        mCVV.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(CustomerInfoActivity.this, "You must fill out the billing info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    finishCustomer();
                }
            }
        });




        mSessionsButton.setEnabled(false);
        mSessionsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerInfoActivity.this, SessionListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        mHomeButton.setEnabled(false);
        mHomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerInfoActivity.this, CustomerListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        mEditButton.setEnabled(false);
        mEditButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerInfoActivity.this, NewCustomerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    public void finishCustomer(){
        boolean isVisa = true;
        switch (mCreditType.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
            case R.id.visa_rb:
                isVisa = true;
                break;
            case R.id.master_card_rb:
                isVisa = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        String cardNum = mCardNum.getText().toString();
        String cardExp = mCardExp.getText().toString();
        String cvv = mCVV.getText().toString();

        // add these values to the customer
        customer.setIsVis(isVisa);
        customer.setCardNum(cardNum);
        customer.setCardExp(cardExp);
        customer.setCvv(cvv);

        Log.d("TAG", "the customer ID that I want to update is : " + customer.getCustomerId().toString());
        Log.d("TAG", "the customer card number before the update: " + customer.getCardNum());

        mCustomerList.updateCustomer(customer);

        Log.d("TAG", "after the update: " + customer.getCardNum());
        Log.d("TAG", "from the updated customer: " + mCustomerList.getCustomer(customerID).getCardNum() + " " +
        "the name " + mCustomerList.getCustomer(customerID).getFirstName());

        mSessionsButton.setEnabled(true);
        mEditButton.setEnabled(true);
        mHomeButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: updateCustomer method code seems correct, you should check or share the code of Activity where updateCustomer method is called

Comment: @shantanu I updated the question to show the Activity where the update method is called. Thanks for looking at it

Comment: First thing I'd do is check whether `update` is updating, that is the `update` method returns the number of rows updated, as an int, so I'd change `mCustomerList.updateCustomer(customer);` to be `int rows_updated = mCustomerList.updateCustomer(customer);`. If 0 then the problem is that the update is not updating for some reason (first guess would be that _id passed is not the _id of an existing row). Perhaps add a simple query to extract a cursor and then get how many rows using csr.getCount(), just before the update.

Comment: I’ve tried to return an int value from the update method and I’m getting 0. Then I called the method getCustomers() and Ilisted out every customer’s first name in the database and it worked just fine. This has really got me baffled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I hope this may help someone in the future. In my constructor for a customer object I generate a random UUID using UUID.randomUUID();

But when I try to pull these values out from the database they are stored in a string and must be inserted into the object to recreate it. Here is the updated CustomerCursorWrapper:

```
public class CustomerCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {

    public CustomerCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    public Customer getCustomer(){
        String customerID = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.CUSTOMER_ID));
        String firstName = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.FIRST_NAME));
        String lastName = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.LAST_NAME));
        String streetAddress = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.STREET_ADDRESS));
        String city = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.CITY));
        String state = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.STATE));
        String zip = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.ZIPCODE));
        String email = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.EMAIL));
        String cardNum = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.CARD_NUM));
        String cardExp = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.CARD_EXP));
        String cvv = getString(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.CVV));
        int isVisa = getInt(getColumnIndex(CustomerTable.Cols.IS_VISA));

        Customer customer = new Customer(firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city,
                state, zip, email, cardNum, cardExp, cvv, isVisa != 0);

        customer.setCustomerId(UUID.fromString(customerID));

        return customer;
    }
}
```